# Disable landscape-mode for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, landscape, meta, portrait

Hi there i created a responsive mobile website using this:

```
max-width(480px) {etc..} 

+

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

For every mobile device the website looks the same => great.

But when i change to landscape there is more than 480px and the website-variation of the desktop displays.

Is there any possibility to disable the auto-rotate or to show the portrait-mode on mobile-device even if there is more than 480px?

Greetings

Comment: Please don't use `maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no`. It provides a  poor user experience and is not recommended.

Comment: `!important` in front of max-width css ,may be it will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and target specific orientation with your media query:

```
@media max-width(600px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    rules for landscaped devices...
}
```

More on media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: in your case: i switch to landscape on mobile device => i get desktop-variation on mobile screen :(

Comment: I forgot you also need the max-width, try the update.

Answer (score 0):

Change your media query to a higher value?

```
max-width(600px) {etc..}
```

Comment: yea i thought about it, but using this i could catch tablet´s etc you know?

Comment: This is really your only option. There are thousands of possible device sizes, you have to draw the line somewhere. For example, the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 phone reports a width of 540px in portrait mode.  Right now, they would be seeing the desktop version of your site.